# Android play expantion downloader sample implement "not a zip error"

Tags: android, expansion

I have problem with downloader_sample in "Android-sdk/extra/google/play_apk_expation"

I make obb file.
one pdf file to zip file, made by 7zip, winrar, etc.. just store not compress.

```
D:\jobb>d:\android-sdk\tools\jobb -pn com.ipetbrand.magazine -d /jobb -o main.2.
com.ipetbrand.magazine.obb -pv 2
Slop: 0   Directory Overhead: 0
Slop: 6047   Directory Overhead: 224
```

but ZipResourceFile occure IOException...

this is logcat msg :

```
11-16 03:06:51.325: D/LVLDownloader(10573): Initialize Download UI
11-16 03:06:51.325: D/DownloaderClientMarshaller(10573): Disconnecting Service bound: false
11-16 03:06:51.365: D/AsyncCopyFromAPKOperation(10573): FileName: /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.ipetbrand.magazine/main.1.com.ipetbrand.magazine.obb
11-16 03:06:51.365: V/zipro(10573): Not a Zip archive
```

help, any one.

[SOLVED] 
don't use for expansion file, android util jobb 
just use zip with no compress, just store.

when you upload that zip file to android market then 
it will be obb file by server.

download it and use by zip.

Answer (score 0):

i think you better using [StorageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html) class instead of read it as zipfile.